# Find the smallest function in a c file

Tags: function, file, words

I have a c(java,c++) file with t functions in it. Is there any way, I can find out the function with smallest no. of words.

Given a function, I can calculate the no.of words in it using yylex().

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: In any programming language - script langauges/c or by using parsers-lexers

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified the language for implementation of the solution, I will propose a description of the algorith I would use.

You can iterate through the file and use regex to detect function prototipes (such as `"^(\w+( )?){2,}\([^!@#$+%^]+?\)"` for C functions). Once you've detected you have a function, you iterate through the next lines and count the words. Once you detect a line containing another function definition, you will store the function with its word count and get to the next until you reach the end of the file.

If we consider you need only the function with the least number of words, you can just store the function name only if it has fewer words than the previous one.